# iframe not rendering page, source of iframe shows only page as text

Tags: html

For the case of simplicity, lets say that I have standard .html document. Now, what I am doing, is surrounding everything in this document like that: `<iframe> {everything} </iframe>`. Now, when I look at the source code of my page, I can see that the page is loaded within the iframe, but is not displayed. Why isn't it displayed?

Edit: Okay, here is a simple example:

```
<iframe>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>asdf</body>
 </html>
</iframe>
```

Save this as .html and fire up - the code will be there, but it wont be displayed. Why?

Comment: Without a live example to display or the code added to the issue here on stackoverflow it's very hard to theorize about what the issue might be.

Comment: @HenrikAmmer: added simple example

Comment: Contents inside `<iframe>` is only rendered by browsers who does not support the iframe (which in these days are almost none). All other wait for a `src="something.html"` attribute.

Comment: Reference http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#edef-IFRAME or http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/special/iframe.html